# How to show in UI FormControl of FormGroup A in middle of FormGroup B

Tags: angular

I have a form with the below structure

```
  this.formGroup = new FormGroup({
      accountId: new FormControl(undefined, [Validators.required]),
      id: new FormControl('', []),
      serviceType: new FormControl('digital', []),
      document: new FormGroup({
        name: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        telephone: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        location: new FormGroup({
          streetAddress: new FormControl('', []),
          locality: new FormControl('', []),
          region: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
          postalCode: new FormControl('', [Validators.pattern('\\d{5}')])
        }),
        categories: new FormArray([
          new FormControl(undefined, [])
        ]),
        isAddressPublishable: new FormControl(false, [])
      })
    });
  }
```

Now, I must show `isAddressPublishable` just above `Locality` in UI.
For this, I am trying like this but it's not working

```
.....Form Above this.......
<ng-container [formGroup]="documentGroup">
          <div class="form-group mb-3">
            <label for="id">Name</label>
            <input formControlName="name" type="text" class="form-control">
            <app-input-feedback [ctrl]="nameCtrl" />
          </div>
          <ng-container [formGroup]="locationGroup">
            <div class="form-group mb-3">
              <label for="streetAddress">Street Address</label>
              <input formControlName="streetAddress" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="123 Main St">
              <app-input-feedback [ctrl]="streetAddressCtrl" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group mb-3">
              <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" formControlName="isAddressPublishable" id="isAddressPublishable" />
                <label class="form-check-label" for="isAddressPublishable">Do not publish this address</label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group mb-3">
              <label for="locality">City/Locality</label>
              <input formControlName="locality" type="text" class="form-control">
              <app-input-feedback [ctrl]="localityCtrl" />
            </div>
......Form After this........
```

Basically, I want to keep the formGroup structure the same in my component.ts file but I want to change how my form will look in the component.html

UI I wish to have

[image: Expected position of isAddressPublishable Checkbox]

The error I get -
[image]

Comment: Can you show us what is the actual result please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it by adding my control in a ng-container which has formgroup of the control like this

````
<ng-container [formGroup]="documentGroup">
          <div class="form-group mb-3">
            <label for="id">Name</label>
            <input formControlName="name" type="text" class="form-control">
            <app-input-feedback [ctrl]="nameCtrl" />
          </div>
          <ng-container [formGroup]="locationGroup">
            <div class="form-group mb-3">
              <label for="streetAddress">Street Address</label>
              <input formControlName="streetAddress" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="123 Main St">
              <app-input-feedback [ctrl]="streetAddressCtrl" />
            </div>
            <ng-container [formGroup]="documentGroup">
              <div class="form-group mb-3">
                <div class="form-check">
                  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" formControlName="isAddressPublishable" id="isAddressPublishable" />
                  <label class="form-check-label" for="isAddressPublishable">Do not publish this address</label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </ng-container>
            <div class="form-group mb-3">
              <label for="locality">City/Locality</label>
              <input formControlName="locality" type="text" class="form-control">
              <app-input-feedback [ctrl]="localityCtrl" />
            </div>```
````

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1.-You can use a getter (it's necessary to "cast" an AbstractControl into a FormControl)

```
  get isAddressPublishableControl(){
    return this.formGroup.get('document.isAddressPublishable') as FormControl
  }
```

And use where you need

```
 <input type="checkbox" [formControl]="isAddressPublishableControl">
```

2.-You can also use a ngModel in standalone way

```
 <input type="checkbox" 
    [ngModel]="formGroup.get('document.isAddressPublishable')?.value"
    (ngModelChange)="
               formGroup.get('document.isAddressPublishable')?.setValue($event)"
    [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}"
 >
```

NOTE: I use this.formGroup, really I don't know if is this.formGroup or this.documentGroup -in your question is not clear-

see [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-hiuslj?file=src%2Fmain.ts)